# IllegalStateException when assigning string to text

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using this code to show a 60 second countdown:

```
timeRemainingText.text = "Time Remaining: 60 Seconds"
            val h = Handler()
            var count = 60
            val r = object : Runnable {
                override fun run() {
                    count--
                    timeRemainingText.text = "Time Remaining: $count Seconds"
                    if (count > 0) h.postDelayed(this, 1000)
                }
            }
            h.postDelayed(r, 1000)
```

I get the following error on line `timeRemainingText.text = "Time Remaining: $count Seconds"`:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.halalrishtey, PID: 1491
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: timeRemainingText must not be null
        at com.mypackage.OTPVerificationFragment$onStart$callbacks$1$onCodeSent$r$1.run(OTPVerificationFragment.kt:117)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Why I'm getting this error, even if count is null, the rest of string should be assigned. Please help!

Comment: Not `count`, Your **TextView** `timeRemainingText` is `null` here.

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: timeRemainingText must not be null`

Comment: Aye you sure you have called 
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` and
`val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.YOUR_TEXT_VIEW_ID)`
before you call this code. Because I just replicated it and it seems to work fine.

Comment: As stated above, can you show where you inflate your view, and how are you retrieving  timeRemainingText?

Comment: @SyedAffanHamdani i'm using kotlin extensions so I don't explicitly call `findViewById()`